# How to set a custom DNS resolver for axios

Tags: node.js, dns, axios

axios uses `http.request` in NodeJs which has an option ([`lookup`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v12.x/docs/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback)) for a custom lookup function. Its default value is `dns.lookup`.

However, we want to use another dns resolver which has the cache ability.

How can I set `lookup` when using axios?

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/94

Comment: Thanks. I have read this issue before. However, is there any way to set the `lookup` option in `http.request` instead of using an interceptor.

Comment: https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2441 :(

Answer (score 0):

Referencing both [Use Custom DNS resolver for any request in NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71074255/use-custom-dns-resolver-for-any-request-in-nodejs) and https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2441, here's how I managed to change the DNS servers used for a single axios client:

```
const resolver = new dns.Resolver();
resolver.setServers([
  '8.8.8.8', // Google
  '1.1.1.1', // Cloudflare
]);
const instance = axios.create({
  // You can do the same thing for the http agent if necessary
  httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
    lookup: (hostname, options, callback) => {
      resolver.resolve4(hostname, (err, addresses) => {
        if (!addresses[0]) {
          throw new Error(`No address found for DNS resolution on ${hostname}`);
        }

        callback(err, addresses[0], 4);
      });
    },
  }),
});
```

You can do a very similar thing if you need to use a resolver that has caching abilities.