# Use Custom DNS resolver for any request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, dns

I'm looking to find a way to use a custom DNS resolver for a nodejs request using node-fetch. I think there is a star of explaining here : [Node override request IP resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026131/node-override-request-ip-resolution) but I can't manage to make it work for any request. My goal is to use an alternative DNS resolver, such as cloudflare (1.1.1.1) or Google public DNS (8.8.8.8) instead the OS / ISP default DNS resolution.

```js
import http from "http";
import https from "https";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

const staticLookup = (ip: string, v?: number) => (hostname: string, _: null, cb: Function) => {
  cb(null, ip, v || 4);
};

const staticDnsAgent = (scheme: "http" | "https", ip: string) => {
  const httpModule = scheme === "http" ? http : https;
  return new httpModule.Agent({ lookup: staticLookup(ip), rejectUnauthorized: false });
};

// Both request are not working
fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=Hello%20World`, {
  agent: staticDnsAgent("https", "1.1.1.1")
})

fetch(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`, {
  agent: staticDnsAgent("http", "8.8.8.8")
})
```

I'm struggling a bit to find a way to make this example work, I'm pretty sure I have to use the nodejs DNS module and set a custom server.

Comment: staticDnsAgent is meant to provide the *IP* of the domain, so in your example, api.github.com is resolved as 1.1.1.1. Instead, resolve with https://github.com/sc0Vu/doh-js-client and use the result inside staticDNSAgent

Comment: Thanks @Martheen I was able to achieve result, see answer below. I used nodejs build in dns module instead external one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to Martheen who answered in my first post I was able to achieve the result here :

```
import http from "http";
import https from "https";
import dns from "dns/promises";
import fetch from "node-fetch";

// Cloud flare dns
dns.setServers([
  "1.1.1.1",
  "[2606:4700:4700::1111]",
]);

const staticLookup = () => async (hostname: string, _: null, cb: Function) => {
  const ips = await dns.resolve(hostname);

  if (ips.length === 0) {
    throw new Error(`Unable to resolve ${hostname}`);
  }

  cb(null, ips[0], 4);
};

const staticDnsAgent = (scheme: "http" | "https") => {
  const httpModule = scheme === "http" ? http : https;
  return new httpModule.Agent({ lookup: staticLookup() });
};

fetch(`https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=Hello%20World`, {
  agent: staticDnsAgent("https")
})

fetch(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`, {
  agent: staticDnsAgent("http")
})
```

Comment: `return new httpModule.Agent({ lookup: staticLookup() });`  should be `  return new httpModule.Agent({ lookup: staticLookup });`

Comment: I solved the issue with this answer and this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35026131/node-override-request-ip-resolution/62808246#62808246

Comment: I ended up with this error when trying your solution 

    Error: queryTxt ENOTFOUND localhost
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] 
    (node:internal/dns/promises:240:17)
    at QueryReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {

And now Im running out of ideas

Comment: I mean it's expected localhost is not a domain name in registrars and only exists locally on your PC DNS records. When you use a custom DNS resolver it's external of your PC and bypassing OS DNS resolver which is the point

Comment: Note that you may want to use `(new dns.Resolver()).setServers` to avoid globally changing the dns servers on the default global dns object.

Answer (score 0):

To use a custom DNS server for all `fetch()` requests in a Node.js script, you can configure a global request agent using the [undici](https://github.com/nodejs/undici) library.

**Step 1:** Install `undici` as follows:

```bash
npm install undici
```

**Step 2:** Set up the global agent with your DNS server configuration:

```js
import { Agent, setGlobalDispatcher } from "undici";

// Replace with your custom DNS server IP
const DnsIp = "127.0.0.1";

const agent = new Agent({
  connect: {
    // The third argument refers to the IP family (4 for IPv4, 6 for IPv6)
    lookup: (_hostname, _options, callback) => callback(null, DnsIp, 4)
  },
});

// Set the custom agent as the global dispatcher
setGlobalDispatcher(agent);

// Example: Use the DNS server at 127.0.0.1 to resolve git.dev
const response = await fetch("https://git.dev/");
```

This has been tested with Node.js v18. Note that the `node-fetch` package is not required.